# Are Japan's Prime Minister visits in Eastern Europe and Economic Partnership Agreement related to US withdrawal from Trans-Pacific Partnership?

Tags: united-states, european-union, japan, trade

[Japan's Prime Minister has visited several countries](https://thediplomat.com/2018/01/what-was-japans-prime-minister-doing-in-eastern-europe/) in the Eastern Europe:

> Japan’s Prime Minister Shinzo Abe returned from an official visit to
>   Romania, wrapping up a five-day tour of three Baltic and three Eastern
>   European countries. Abe toured six countries over five days — Estonia,
>   Latvia, Lithuania, Bulgaria, Serbia, and Romania — seeking to bolster
>   political diplomacy and bilateral business links in the region as well
>   as addressing regional security issues.

About a month earlier, [Japan and EU finalized Economic Partnership Agreement](https://ec.europa.eu/commission/news/eu-and-japan-finalise-economic-partnership-agreement-2017-dec-08-0_en)

> Trade Commissioner Cecilia Malmström and Japanese Foreign Minister
>   Taro Kono announced today the successful conclusion of the final
>   discussions on the EU-Japan Economic Partnership Agreement.

About one year ago, Trump withdrawn from [Trans-Pacific Partnership](https://www.theguardian.com/us-news/2017/jan/23/donald-trump-first-orders-trans-pacific-partnership-tpp):

> Donald Trump has begun his effort to dismantle Barack Obama’s legacy,
>   formally scrapping a flagship trade deal with 11 countries in the
>   Pacific rim.

[Japan's Prime Minister reaction](http://www.bbc.com/news/business-32498715) was that TPP without US does not make sense:

> Japan's Prime Minister Shinzo Abe has said a TPP without the US - and
>   its market of 250 million consumers - would be "meaningless".

When Shinzo Abe visited Romania, some local analysts argued that this historical visit (first time visit from a Japanese high official in some of the countries) is related to US withdrawal from Trans-Pacific Partnership. However, I could not find any reference to sustain this. It makes sense, since Japan might feel that it has to compensate US boycott of TPP.

**Question:** Are Japan's Prime Minister visits in Eastern Europe and Economic Partnership Agreement related to US withdrawal from Trans-Pacific Partnership?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strictly speaking the visit had a [few main objectives](https://thediplomat.com/2018/01/what-was-japans-prime-minister-doing-in-eastern-europe/):

- The [EU-Japan EPA](http://ec.europa.eu/trade/policy/in-focus/eu-japan-economic-partnership-agreement/).
- Maximizing international pressure over North Korea.
- Trying to keep up with the increased influence of China over the Eastern European countries.

Answering directly to your question, although the EU-Japan EPA is not related to the recent US administration decisions (it started in 2013), there seems to be some urgency accelerating its implementation, most likely due the US [withdrawal from the TTP](https://www.nytimes.com/2017/12/08/business/economy/eu-japan-trade.html) (emphasis mine).

> Tokyo and Brussels began trade talks in 2013, and said in June that
>   they were nearing a deal. Japan trades less with the European Union
>   than it does with the United States or China. **But completing a deal**
>   **with the European Union became a more urgent priority for Tokyo after**
>   **President Trump’s decision in January to withdraw the United States**
>   **from another agreement, the Trans-Pacific Partnership**. Japan has also
>   pushed to revive that deal, even without the United States.

The recent events related to US-Japan relations have not been mentioned but I think the [joint statement released by EU-Japan in December - 2017](http://europa.eu/rapid/press-release_STATEMENT-17-5182_en.htm) says enough (emphasis is mine):

> Beyond its considerable economic value, the finalisation of EU-Japan
>   EPA is of strategic importance.  **Amid widening protectionist**
>   **movements**, the finalisation of the negotiations on the EU-Japan EPA
>   demonstrates to the world the firm political will of Japan and the EU
>   to keep the flag of free trade waving high and powerfully advance free
>   trade.